# No actualiza la columna con clausula "update"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

> Estoy tratando de aplicar esta actualizacion de registro en tabla, no genera error, pero tampoco ejecuta el update, al hacer la consulta de tabla no realiza los cambios.
>   Agradezco ayuda.

```
while True:

    opcionMenu = input("inserta un numero valor >> ")
    try:
        opcionMenu = str(opcionMenu)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        if opcionMenu == "A":
            print("Has pulsado la Opcion Modificar Numero de Documento Empleado")
            numdocEmp = int(input("Digite el idCodigo del Empleado a Modificar :"))
            nuevonumdocEmp = int(input("Digite el Nuevo numero de Docuemnto del Empleado a Modificar :"))

            nuevo = ("update(Empleados).where(numdocEmp == '%S').values(nuevonumdocEmp)")

            session.flush(nuevo)
            session.commit()
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de actualizar una tabla, usando `sqlalchemy.update` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
from sqlalchemy import update

if opcionMenu == "A":
    print("Has pulsado la Opcion Modificar Numero de Documento Empleado")
    numdocEmp = int(input("Digite el idCodigo del Empleado a Modificar :"))
    nuevonumdocEmp = int(input("Digite el Nuevo numero de Docuemnto del Empleado a Modificar :"))

    stmt = update(Empleado)\
        .where(Empleado.numdocEmp == numdocEmp)\
        .values(numdocEmp = nuevonumdocEmp)
    session.execute(stmt)
    session.commit()
```

Donde `Empleado` es tu clase base mapeada, cuyas instancias forma las filas de tu tabla `empleados`.

---

Otra opción muy simple si usas el sistema declarativo es obteniendo la fila o filas con `query` y luego simplemente modificar los atributos que quieras:

- Cargando los objetos:

  ```
  if opcionMenu == "A":
      print("Has pulsado la Opcion Modificar Numero de Documento Empleado")
      numdocEmp = int(input("Digite el idCodigo del Empleado a Modificar :"))
      nuevonumdocEmp = int(input("Digite el Nuevo numero de Docuemnto del Empleado a Modificar :"))

      rows = session.query(Empleado).filter(Empleado.numdocEmp == numdocEmp)
      if rows:
          for row in rows:
              row.numdocEmp = nuevonumdocEmp
          session.commit()
      else:
          print("Número no encontrado")
  ```

  En este caso se supone que solo va a existir una fila con ese valor, no obstante se puede iterar sobre el resultado completo en vez de usar `first()` si esto no es así.
- Directamente sobre la base de datos (usando el método `update` de `query`):

  ```
  if opcionMenu == "A":
      print("Has pulsado la Opcion Modificar Numero de Documento Empleado")
      numdocEmp = int(input("Digite el idCodigo del Empleado a Modificar :"))
      nuevonumdocEmp = int(input("Digite el Nuevo numero de Docuemnto del Empleado a Modificar :"))

      session.query(Empleado)\
          .filter(Empleado.numdocEmp==numdocEmp)\
          .update({"numdocEmp": nuevonumdocEmp})
      session.commit()
  ```

Como apunte, a la hora de depurar este tipo de problemas "silenciosos" es muchas veces de ayuda especificar el parámetro `echo` como `True` al declarar el motor de la base de datos:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///myexampledb.db', echo=True)
```

Esto nos permite ir viendo por consola con bastante detalle todas las interacciones entre SQLAlchemy y la propia base de datos.

Comment: FJSevilla, buscando respuestas y en esa coincido contigo, aplicando una query primero y luego la clausula  update, me esta realizando la actualizacion, el problema fue que me lo aplico a toda la tabla con el mismo valor, y lo necesito sobre un campo especifico.

Comment: Pero veo que tu ejemplo lo especifica bien,  la clave debe ser numdocEmp, para realizar el cambio, en este caso. Ya lo ejecute y excelente era lo que buscaba. me realiza los cambios donde lo necesito. gracias nuevamente FJ. y Feliz Navidad